# Soap: <faultstring> 11|Session|</faultstring>

Tags: php, curl, soap

I am getting faultcode error with soap as per below while using soap request with php.

```
<soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring> 11|Session|</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body>
```

Kindly suggest about this error.

I am using below code in PHP :

```
$request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="..>
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <MessageID>...   
      <oas:Security xmlns:..">
         <oas:UsernameToken oas1:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            ...
         </oas:UsernameToken>
      </oas:Security>

      <awsse:Session TransactionStatusCode="Start" xmlns:awsse="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3"/>
   </soapenv:Header>   
   <soapenv:Body>
      ....
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';



 $soapaction = "..";
 $url           = "..";

 $headers = array(
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
        "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
        "SOAPAction: $soapaction",
        "Connection: Keep-Alive",
        "Host: nodeD1.test.com",
        "User-Agent: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        "Content-length: ".strlen($request)
 );

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 $response      = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have tried with $client->__doRequest method with SoapClient class.

Comment: COuld you please show your code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you able to resolve the above issue????

Answer (score 0):

Usually this causes from authentication issue. The request which you constructed could not reach the resources on target because of incorrect authentication or header data. please try this it will work.

-You should check all parameters in `<soapenv:Header>.`

-Username in the `UserToken` might be missing or incorrect.